# Import-CSV in PowerShell hides double quotes

Tags: csv, powershell, quotes

I import a file and process its content like this:

```
$msg = Import-Csv .\content -Delimiter "`t" | Select msg | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String | %{$_ -replace "\n"}
```

In this case the content-File looks like this:

```
id  name    when    ip  msg user_id
 50 Felix   2015-07-22 12:51:04 10.1.100.6  "ein link":www.link.de  89
```

But $msg gives back the following:

```
ein link:www.link.de
```

---

When I've a content-File like this:

```
id  name    when    ip  msg user_id
 50 Felix   2015-07-22 12:51:04 10.1.100.6  dies ist "ein link":www.link.de 89
```

$msg is correct:

```
dies ist "ein link":www.link.de
```

Import-CSV only hides the double quotes when they stand at the beginning of the text.

I'm working with PowerShell 5.0

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe it works:

```
$msg = Get-Content .\content.csv |
       ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ('"','"""') } | 
       ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter "`t" | 
       Select msg | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | 
       Out-String | %{$_ -replace "\n"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution takes care of the problem with double quotes at the beginning. But now, when I've double quotes somewhere in the middle of text I get output like this: dies ist """ein link""":www.link.de

Comment: @FLX Ok, I've tested it and using your example works but 'cause I cannot test any case I wrote 'maybe it works' ;). You can try replacing double quote with a single quote, this way works in my test.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case it is not possible to use single quotes instead of double quotes. Is there another solution?

Comment: @FLX Maybe using regex you can match all before `:www` and add the double quote to the match.

Comment: Ok. Now I push the content-File into a variable and process it like this: $content -replace '^(.+?)\t"(.+?)"(.+?)$', '$1`t"""$2"$3'; So I add two double quotes which can be removed by import-csv. But I don't know how to insert the tab back. `t gives back `t ...